# Heredoc syntax pushing values into arrays

Tags: php, arrays, heredoc

I get a syntax error when I use heredoc syntax to push values into array

```
$theArray = array();

$theArray[] = <<<EOT
some values here
EOT;

$theArray[] = <<<EOT
some values here
EOT;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code.

Comment: be sure that there isn't any space before `EOT;`

Comment: Your code is working fine, May be you have an error in some where else? can you post your error_log here ?

Comment: And make sure there isn't anything after `<<<EOD` a space, a tab, etc.

Comment: I have no access to error log, anyway even my editor seems not to be happy with that syntax http://i42.tinypic.com/2s8snz8.gif

Comment: @gabric: That's not a PHP error. It's specific to your IDE. I suggest you edit the question and add this detail.

Comment: @AmalMurali: actually I'm getting a blank page when I try to run this code into the webserver. If I just remove one of the array assignments it works fine.

Comment: @gabric: Add the following to the very top of your script (to enable error reporting) and refresh the page: `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work just fine. Doing a `print_r($theArray);` would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => some values here
    [1] => some values here
)
```

[Demo.](http://3v4l.org/8Mfb7)

If you're getting parse errors, double-check and make sure there is no whitespace after the three angled brackets in the beginning and/or end.

Comment: I just noticed that there was a white space after the three brackets... thanks for the support